# Unable to correlate MongoId::getPID returned PID with 7th and 8th byte

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have 2 confusion regarding process ID in MongoID object.

As per documentation byte 7 and 8 denotes PID. here '0a3d' HEX value that is 7th and 8th byte.

How is returned PID 15620 related to '0a3d' ?

And every time PID returned by getPID is different(but near 15620).

Can some please explain?

```
$id = new MongoId('4f7351390c211d0a3d000004');
print_r($id);

//MongoId Object ( [$id] => 4f7351390c211d0a3d000004 ) 

print_r($id->getpID());

//15620
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.getpid.php

getPID() returns the PID used to create this MongoId, so its returning the process id in the context of which you ran this code. I don't think it is doing what you are expecting it to do, that is pull off the 7th and 8th byte.

I created a PHP issue to track this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-359